# PhpMyAdmin password

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1045

I get the error #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
after I accidentaly changed the password in phpmyadmin for root and 127.0.0.1 . the problem is i cannot change common.lib.php. I want to revert these changes in mysql somehow... Doe to the security of the server i cannot change much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I've used phpMyAdmin, but if I'm not mistaken, it stores it's passwords in the mysql database it self. So, if you are able to get access to the [command-line of the server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html), you are able to change the password using simple SQL statements.

Comment: I have done this, using the command line i have added in mysql.users user 127.0.0.1 with all priviliages, and killed a process and it worked like a charm. The problem was that I couldn`t stop XAMPP, and couldn`t edit any files of XAMPP (the default ones at least), and I couldn`t kill the processes, and restart wasn`t an option...complicated. And i couldn`t install anything... Admin Rights on server :|

Answer (score 3):

I hope you can access the mysql server administration. As I know the root is the main user in MySQL it'll be a problem if you cannot access it. If you have a user with the same level, try to change the password there if possible.

Here's the step on how to reset the root password in MySQL

- [How to Reset the Root Password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)

I was also dependent in phpmyadmin before until I know sqlyog and MySQL Query Browser and WorkBench. Have a look on this as an alternative on phpmyadmin.

- [Download MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)
- [SQLyog free download](http://sqlyog.en.softonic.com/download)

Answer (score 0):

Go to /etc/phpmyadmin folder.
Open config-db.php

Here you will find your default username and password