# change password for the php mysql for the ftp server like 68.15.25.77/phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

when I am trying to acces the phpmysqlpannel for server lets say 67.56.88.25/phpmyadmin

it gives the following error
MySQL said: Documentation

## 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

how to change the password to access the phpmysql pannel from the above server I am using winscp to upload the files on server

Comment: possible duplicate of [PhpMyAdmin password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659634/phpmyadmin-password)

Answer (score -1):

Who or what are you using for a server?

If you are using a local server such as XAMPP or MAMP then there should be a configuration file for the password. The default is usually a blank password.

If you are using a webhost such as GoDaddy you can change your password in the control panel after logging into the MySQL section.

Comment: I already mentioned that I have right to access 67.56.88.25 using some password and username which I have accessed through winscp but when I am trying to open 67.56.88.25/phpmyadmin  that shows the above error .now my Question is to how and where I am able change  the password.