# PHPMyAdmin requires password

Tags: phpmyadmin

Sorry for posting again about this. I looked at all the solutions I could find and none worked for me.
I downloaded PHPMyAdmin from their site. Extracted and placed the folder in `/Sites`.
Went to `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/setup/index.php` and added a new server.
In authentication I kept it cookie and "root" as user and did not add a password.
Then went to `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` and it's asking for a password.

I tried empty, just root as user. root as user and the MySQL root password. Tried clearing the cache. Checked "Allow logins without a password" in "Server configuration". Nothing helps.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into these issues, these might help you to find the solution:

[PhpMyAdmin password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659634/phpmyadmin-password?rq=1)

[Resetting MySQL Root Password with XAMPP on Localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566453/resetting-mysql-root-password-with-xampp-on-localhost)

[Create a root password for PHPMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224431/create-a-root-password-for-phpmyadmin)